# Set width of a div exponentially with [style.width.%]

Tags: html, ng-style, angularjs-ng-style

I want to set the width of a div let say 7% of its container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;

  .cell {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        1
    </div>
     <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        2
    </div>
     <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        3
    </div>
     <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        4
    </div>
     <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        5
    </div>
     <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        6
    </div>
     <div class="cell" [style.width.%]="100/7">
        7
    </div>
</div>
```

The cell items should be horizontally scrollable, it seems like it's not working. Any help please?

Comment: what kind of syntax are you using? this is clearly not CSS. Add the relevant tags if you are using something else

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry, I just did

Comment: if I transform it to a html/css, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ro1gswz4/

Comment: @TemaniAfif still they are not equal cause there is a scroll and the 7-th item is not showing correctly. the idea is that I want to show them expanded equally to the screen based on the divider.  `width:calc(100%/7)` means that i want to show 7 items,  `width:calc(100%/6)` means that i want to show 6 items in the visible screen.

Comment: add     box-sizing: border-box; to the element

Comment: @TemaniAfif genius, yes that resolved it, thank you, man.